# Access an instance of a class from anonymous class argument

Tags: java, actionlistener, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I can't seem to find an answer to this through all the anonymous inner class questions on the site.

```
public void start()
{
    /* Ask the user to login */
    final LoginFrame login;
    login = new LoginFrame(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event)
        {
            switch (event.getActionCommand())
            {
                case "login":
                    /* @todo Login the user */
                    String username = login.getUsername();
                    String password = login.getPassword();
            }
        }
    });
    login.display();
}
```

My login frame takes in an `ActionListener`. How do I access `login` from within the `new ActionListener()`?

Right now I'm getting an error:

> Variable login may not have been initialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can't because the `ActionListener` will be created first and at that time must have access to the final variable `login` which isn't initialized yet.

The order of calls would be like this:

- create an instance of the `ActionListener`
- pass that instance to the `LoginFrame` constructor
- assign the created frame to `login`

Now assume the `ActionListener` constructor would access `login` - it wouldn't be initialized yet and would cause an error.

To fix this you'd need to create the frame first and then set the `ActionListener`, i.e.

```
final LoginFrame login = new LoginFrame();
login.addActionListener( new ActionListener() { ... } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to assign the `ActionListener` after the `LoginFrame` has been created.

The right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated first or prior to the `login` field being assigned as the compiler is telling you.

It's more common for with *listeners* is to have an `add` method, so I'd change the code to read:

```
private final login = new LoginFrame();

login.addActionListener(
  new ActionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event)
    {
      switch (event.getActionCommand())
      {
        case "login":
          /* @todo Login the user */
          String username = login.getUsername();
          String password = login.getPassword();
      }        
    }      
  }
);    

login.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized your variable `login` and you are using it.

By your `anonymous class`, you are initializing your variable, so you can use it after initializing it. And if you want to use this variable, you have to initialize it (but never initialize your variable with `null` value because you are using methods of `LoginFrame` class and it must throw `NullPointerException`).